# How to add (document).ready to an existing jquery function file

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function file with function with AJAX functions in it. Now I need to add **(document).ready** function to the same file. My question is should I add this function outside of the existing function() block or keep it inside.

Comment: What is inside this "jquery function file"?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it outside, if it's like so:

```
function doMyAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        stuff: more 
        ect...
    }).done(function(data) {
        $(element).html(data);
    });

    $("element").on('DOMNodeModified', function(event) {
        $(event.target).appendTo('body');
    });
}

$(function() {  //same as $(document).ready(function(){..});
    doMyAjax(); //function is executed after DOM is ready
});
```

or you can wrap all your code in it:

```
$(function() {  //same as $(document).ready(function(){..});
    //all my code goes here and is executed after DOM is ready
});
```

Up 2 u !

Answer (score 0):

Add the $(document).ready() function outside of your included file, and from there call a function in your file to do whatever you need to do in you other code. i.e.

```
var myStuff = myStuff || {
   init: function() {
     ///run stuff needed in document.ready here
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    myStuff.init();
});
```

The golden rule here is to call $(document).ready in only 1 place from each page.